# how to remove space between jtextfield, jbutton and raisedbevel border

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, border-layout, jpasswordfield

I wants to remove blank space or border space between `JButton` and `JTextfield` added inside `raisedbevel` border 
I tried this code but still gap between them

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("JPasswordField  ");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel p=new JPanel(),pp=new JPanel();
    JButton b=new JButton("o");

b.setBorder(null);
b.setBorderPainted(false);
b.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
 Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
    b.setBorder(emptyBorder);
    Border  raisedbevel=BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();


    pp.setBorder(raisedbevel);
    JTextField t=new JTextField(20);
    t .setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    t.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
    b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 25));
    pp.setBackground(Color.black);
    pp.add(t);

     pp.add(b);


     p.add(pp);
    f.add(p);
    f.setSize(400, 100);
    f.setVisible(true);


  }
}
```

I wants to remove that black space completely
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JPanel` use a `FlowLayout` by default, which uses a padding of `5`, vertically and horitzontially, by default.

If you want to continue using `FlowLayout`, you could specify the padding you want using something like...

```
pp = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

or use another layout manager, like `GridBagLayout`.

I'd also discourage you from using `setPreferredSize` generally and rely on `Border`'s and layout's to affect how a component might be "extra" sized beyond its default preferred size.

Have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), [How to Use FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html), [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) and [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)